# Does startForegroundService() replace WakefulBroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, foreground-service

WakefulBroadcastReceiver is deprecated and the documentation says that you should use a JobScheduler instead. Of course, this does not make sense if you actually want to start a service.

I am hoping that startForegroundService() does not suffer from the fact that you need to hold a WakeLock while starting it from the background. Is this the case?